# Javascript - Get 'external' HTML document body

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website which resides in a directory.  On a particular user operation that website's javascript needs to get the body from an 'external' HTML document which resides in an immediate subdirectory of the primary webpage.

Example:
Primary webpage directory
|___  TutorialFiles (the 'external' HTML document subdirectory)

When the user clicks on a link it executes its OnClick() javascript function.
The following is what I am trying to use, but it is not working.

```
function DisplayDocument(thisDoc) {
    //alert("Display " + thisDoc + " Doc Here!");

    var loc = window.location.pathname;
    var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));

    var HTMLDoc = "./TutorialFiles" + "/" + thisDoc;

    var HTMLDocContent = getBody(HTMLDoc);
    document.getElementById("page_content_wrapper").innerHTML = getBody(HTMLDocContent);
    return false;
}

function getBody(content) { 
   var x = content.indexOf("<body");
   x = content.indexOf(">", x);    
   var y = content.lastIndexOf("</body>"); 
   return content.slice(x + 1, y);
}
```

That above javascript code does not 'see' the external document in the subdirectory  TutorialFiles and therefore cannot get its 'body'.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: At no point are you actually loading the HTML source code of the second document. You have to use AJAX for that. (Your function, the one that looks for `<body`, receives the path to the document, not magically its contents. You're also calling the function twice.)

Answer (score 0):

You can load the html files using `XMLHttpRequest`. Here is a code snippet based on your code that loads an external html into the page.

To adapt to your case simply change the `serverPath` to you own server and it should work:

```js
var serverPath = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/dist/';

var loadHtml = function(path, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', path, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState !== 4) return;
    if (this.status !== 200) return;
    callback(this.responseText);
  };
  xhr.send();
};

var displayHtml = function(file) {
  loadHtml(serverPath + file, function(html) {
    document.querySelector('.page_content_wrapper').innerHTML = html;
  });
  return false;
};
```

```html
<button onclick="displayHtml('index.html');">Load html</button>
<div class="page_content_wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  I'll try the code and see how it works.  One remaining question is how to represent the sub-directory itself -- not as a fully defined path (as your serverPath shows above), but instead as a relative path from the primary page's directory?   Should it be  "./TutorialFiles" or what?

Comment: Maybe I have the syntax for the relative path to the 'external' HTML document set wrong, but when I try the code, it executes with no error, but it does not bring the HTML document into the page_content_wrapper.

Comment: Try the full path of your server. Also check your console for errors, there you should see the request that is made, and do corrections based on that.

Comment: A relative path should also work, its all mater of using the correct value. Without seeing your code and having details about your server its hard to tell.

Comment: Also log the request: `xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { console.log(this);` to gather more info of the possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, once again when all of the suggestions did not do what I needed, I ended up resolving the issue myself.

What I ended up with used some code that was already working for me in controlling my Sidebar menu onClick() events.  I had not thought to use that for this additional functionality, but it worked.

The Sidebar onClick=MenuClick('TutorialFiles/' &  & ',' &  & "')"

So with a codebehind searchBtn() function I merely built the the onClick() methods for the links found in the Search results to the same thing and it began working.

```
    //--- Function to Load 'External' HTML Page (doc) into Content Wrapper ---
    function MenuClick(doc, displayText) {
        var MasterPgPrefix = "";
        var titlebox = document.getElementById(MasterPgPrefix + 'txtTutorialTitle');
        titlebox.value = displayText;
        titlebox.style.visibility = "visible";
        titlebox.style.display = "block";

        var Tutorial = doc;
        var DisplayObj = "<object id='ThisObj' type='text/html' data='" + Tutorial + "' style='min-width:100%; min-height: 101%; overflow: hidden'></object>";
        document.getElementById("page_content_wrapper").innerHTML = DisplayObj;
    }
```

Thank you for your advise and suggestions.